# How to Mock EntityManagerFactory In JUNIT

Tags: java, junit, entitymanagerfactory

JUNIT Test How To Mock Entity Manager Factory. i'm writing junit test case for Entity Manager Factory but here in side when (when().then()) getting null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` at the top of you Test class.

Refer this https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/4.4.0/org/mockito/junit/jupiter/MockitoExtension.html

This code is working for me. You should remove @ExtendWith (SpringExtension.class). Also remove that Mockito.mock since we have added @Mock on top of those fields.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
    
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TestClass {

    @Mock
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @Mock
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    @Mock
    private CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;
    @Mock
    private CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery;

    @Test
    void getSearchData() {
        when(entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()).thenReturn(entityManager);
        when(entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(criteriaBuilder);
        when(criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class)).thenReturn(criteriaQuery);
        when(criteriaQuery.from(User.class)).thenReturn(new Root<>());//you can also mock Root object
    }
}
```

Comment: With this annotation also getting same null value from  EntityManagerFactory...Please provide me another solution so i can try that.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet that you are trying?

Comment: Autowired
 private EntityManagerFactory postgresEntityManagerFactory;
 EntityManager em = postgresEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
          CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
          CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
          
          Root<User> cdRet = cq.from(User.class);
          List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: I'm Autowired EntityManagerFactory postgresEntityManagerFactory and trying to mock like above code...

Comment: Mock
 private EntityManager entityManager;

Atowired Test
void getSearchData() {
entityManager = Mockito.mock(EntityManager.class);
 EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Mockito.mock(EntityManagerFactory.class);
when(entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()).thenReturn(entityManager);

Comment: I tried Above code in junit test case

Comment: Yes i'm Using @Mock only on EntityManagerFactory

Comment: Will you be able to post your full test file in you question with formatting. It will be easier to understand there. :)

Comment: ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) class User {                                         
Mock                                                    
private EntityManager entityManager; Test                                                            
void getSearchData(){entityManager= Mockito.mock(EntityManager.class); EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory=Mockito.mock(EntityManagerFactory.class); when(entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()).thenReturn(entityManager);}} \\I removed sine from annotations because stackoverflow is not allowing so please

Comment: Try code in the updated answer.

Comment: Whatever code u sent it's Very useful for me Thank you so much for this
 but As i mention in my previous comment [Autowired private EntityManagerFactory postgresEntityManagerFactory; EntityManager em = postgresEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(); CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder(); CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class); Root<User> cdRet = cq.from(User.class);]

After em value : em.getCriteriaBuilder(); CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
error will throw because CriteriaQuery is not mocked thats

Comment: Please see once my above comment Because whatever code you sent i agree it's mocking EntityManagerFactory but whenever we want some value from EntityManagerFactory it will we null because we are only mocking not giving any value ...so please I will reach my ending solution

Comment: you just need to mock other objects as well. Do when().then() for others as well.